# Number of irrational roots of the equation $(x-1)(x-2)(3x-2)(3x+1)=21$?

Tags: roots, irrational-numbers

The number of irrational roots of the equation $(x-1)(x-2)(3x-2)(3x+1)=21$ is

(A)0

(B)2

(C)3

(d)4

Actually im a 10 class student i don't know any of it,but my elder brother(IIT Coaching) cannot solve them,he told me post these questions on this site someone might know the answers and for now he is not in the town. So can you please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: For an approach different from the excellent hints given, you can use the Rational Roots Theorem.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, you still have to figure out the total number of real roots though.

Comment: Maybe. Depends on meaning one assigns to irrational.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$(x-1)(3x-2)=3x^2-5x+2$ and $(x-2)(3x+1)=3x^2-5x-2$

Put $3x^2-5x=u$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$(x-2)(3x+1)=3x^2-5x-2$$
$$(x-1)(3x-2)=3x^2-5x+2$$

If you denote $3x^2-5x$ by $y$ you get

$$(y-2)(y+2)=21$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No problem, to be honest, when I saw that you posted the same answer just before me I wasn't sure if I should leave it up or not :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
$$ (3x-2)(x-1) = 3x^2-5x+2 $$
and 
$$ (3x+1)(x-2) = 3x^2 -5x-2 $$

$$ (x-1)(x-2)(3x-2)(3x+1) = (3x^2-5x-2)(3x^2-5x+2) = 21 $$
Now put
$$ 3x^2-5x = t $$
$$ (t-2)(t+2) = 21 $$
Now, solve

Comment: have you seen the other two answers?

Comment: No, i don't. Otherwise i wouldn't answer this question. Actually i am learning LaTex,that's why i take more time than you people in writing my answer.